# How to fix 'wrong row length' error when adding a row to a CIF file with the Python GEMMI library

Tags: python

Based on the documentation [here](https://gemmi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cif.html#dom-and-sax), I tried to add a row to my CIF file using the Python GEMMI library as follows:

```py
loop = block.find_loop('_atom_type.symbol').get_loop()
loop.add_row(['Au'], pos=0)
loop.add_row(['Zr'])  # appends
list(block.find_loop('_atom_type.symbol'))
['Au', 'C', 'CL', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'S', 'Zr']
```

However, I received the following error:

```
(RuntimeError: add_row(): wrong row length.)
```

I tried different positions with `loop.add_row()` to no avail.

How do I add rows?

Comment: my main issue was that I have a structure from VESTA and I want to add some cations to that structure. I added them using VESTA. The PROBLEM is that I can't do that with python using gemmi library or ASE environment using atoms module or ase.io

Comment: is this related https://github.com/project-gemmi/gemmi/issues/120

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (as suggested by the developer of the library) is to use a list of strings:

```
loop.add_row(
    ['Na1', '1.0', '0.141800', '0.000000', '0.667300', 'Uiso', '0.050000', 'Na']
)
```

---

**Old solution**

I originally solved this problem by reading the CIF file (that was produced by VESTA after adding the cations) as a normal plain text file with Python; adding all the necessary information to arrays and then writing a new CIF file using the GEMMI library with the new added atoms that were copied to the arrays.

If anybody is experienced with the GEMMI library, please let me know why there is a problem when adding rows of new atoms to the CIF file.